# Simple Crossbrowser textarea expander

Tags: jquery, css, textarea, prop

My previously simple textarea expander is now causing problems.

```
$(document).on('keyup', 'textarea',function(){
        $(this).height($(this).prop('scrollHeight'));
    });
```

Works fine on Firefox but on webkit browsers keeps increasing the text-area in size on every key press whether it needs to or now.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Looks like you're looking for this. http://www.jacklmoore.com/autosize

Comment: Never been a fan of plugins. I concede I was wrong... That is a very good little bit of script.

Comment: Yupp, and it's only 2kb so not much to worry about.

Comment: Yeah, that is a sweet bit of script!